# Switch on and off an electronic device within a time range e.g: 8am to 3pm

Tags: switches, power-electronics

i am wondering if anyone know how to adjust an electronic device so it can work on a specific timeframe, I have a water pump, I would like to make it work only within a determined time range, for example 8 am to 4pm, I was thinking to use raspberry pi but I think that's beyond the need. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. Plug-in 24-hour timers are available in all countries and in many formats, analogue and digital.*

- Set the clock.
- Set the on-times.
- Plug timer into socket.
- Plug pump into timer.

Comment: I can't explain how much grateful i am for this advice, I didn't even know it exist, Thanks a lot!

Comment: All the UK plugs and UK/Ireland URLs, I'm surprised to see the one NEMA 5-15 in the bottom middle!

Answer (score -3):

You can use a monostable multivibrator . Your astable circuit should have a period of 8hours , every time the multivibrator gets triggered it will return to the stable condition after 8 hours.

Comment: I appreciate your help, thanks

Comment: This will desynchronize with clock time rather quickly. Far better to use an RTC or even just count power line cycles.